# Catching InvalidArgumentException in template

Tags: joomla-3.3.x

I need to access an instance of JImage in a template and when calling

```
$image->getPath()
```

want to catch InvalidArgumentException in case the image file is not on disk.

I tried:

```
try{
    echo $image->getPath();
}catch (Exception $e){
    $test = 1;
}
```

But instead of catching the Exception the debugger always leads me to

```
/libraries/cms/error/page.php, function render(Exception $error)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[get->Path()](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/joomla/image/image.php#L466) method actually does not throw an Exception, so you can not catch it. `InvalidArgumentException` is thrown in [loadFile()](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/joomla/image/image.php#L527) method, so may be you should use it for your check.

Comment: Absolutely correct, thanks for pointing this out.